# How to automate a UIPickerView to select particular item using KIF?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, xctest, kif

I have a `UIPickerView` showing some numbers [4,5,6,7,8]. I want to automate picker view to select a number 6. For that i'm trying by using following code.

```
tester().tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel("height field")// picker view is input view for the text field
tester().waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("size picker")
tester().selectPickerViewRowWithTitle("6")
```

But the test failing with error "the uidatepicker does not have the expected column count". I am unable to solve this issue. Any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this here:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView accessibilityLabelForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return @"height field";
}
```

The problem which I had was, that I used:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
```

instead of:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

It seems that KIF doesn't support attributed texts to select in a UIPickerView

Comment: after the latest update. It now supports also attributedTitles.